# array_search can't find element which is clearly there

Tags: php

Why does the following code work:

```
$test = array(0=>'test1','field0'=>'test2',1=>'test3','field1'=>'test4');
echo array_search('test4',$test);
```

But the following doesn't:

```
$test = array(0=>0,'field0'=>'test2',1=>'test3','field1'=>'test4');
echo array_search('test4',$test);
```

If you had a mixed array from say mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH) and took the keys which you needed to search you wouldn't be able too - it would never progress further than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do `array_search('test4',$test, TRUE);`.  The 3rd parameter tells it to use `===` instead of `==` when comparing.

Since your array holds both strings and numbers, when it compares to the `0` (the 1st element), it converts `'test4'` to a number (it stops at the 1st non-numeric character) and it happens to match.

What I mean is: `'test4' == 0` => `0 == 0` => `true`.

When you pass `TRUE` as the 3rd parameter, it uses `===`, and `'test4' === 0` is automatically `false` since the types don't match, there is no conversion.

Comment: I had seen this in the manual but failed to fully appreciate that it would solve that issue so thanks Rocket. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution = force the 0 value to be a string:

```
$test = array(0=>0,'field0'=>'test2',1=>'test3','field1'=>'test4');
foreach ($test as $k=>$v){ $test[$k] = (string) $v; }
echo array_search('test4',$test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't search a number for a string and expect a good result.

My guess is it sees the value as a number, so it converts your string to a number (which it can't) so that string gets converted to a 0.  So the value of 0 equals the search string, which also equals 0, and there's your result.

If the value is 1, it won't match as the search string gets converted to a 0 (as you can't convert a string to a number) so it wouldn't match in the following.

$test = array(0=>1,'field0'=>'test2',1=>'test3','field1'=>'test4');

You'll only get your exact case scenario when that value in the array is 0.